# How to show post(excerpt) from specific category on wp page?

Tags: posts, categories, pages, sidebar, excerpt

I need this on 3 pages, all 3 from different categories, and then to show several post excerpts from all 3 categories in sidebar of home page.

Answer (score 2):

The Easiest way to do that would be to use [**List category posts**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) plugin which allows you to list posts from a category into a post/page using the [catlist] shortcode.

you can also use this shortcode in a simple text widget and add just add :

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

to your theme's functions.php file, which will tell WordPress to render shortcodes in widgets.